# Can I use Coffeescript and ERB in the same file and keep readable indentation?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, erb, indentation

In Rails, I have a Coffeescript file in my views that gets rendered as the response to an AJAX request.

If I have some ERB control logic using `<% %>`, Id' like to be able to indent everything logically like I would in an HTML view:

```
exampleFunction = ->
  <% if condition %>
    alert("condition met!")
  <% else %>
    alert("condition not met!")
  <% end %>
```

But this usually means the Coffeescript throws indentation errors and won't compile. *(The example I just gave might not fail, I haven't bothered to check, but it happens all the time in less contrived cases.)*

So I have to indent things in this rather unwieldy way:

```
exampleFunction = ->
  <% if condition %>
  alert("condition met!")
  <% else %>
  alert("condition not met!")
  <% end %>
```

Is there any other way around this? Can I get Coffeescript and ERB to play nicely with eachother and allow for more readable indentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't quite answer the question, but I'd suggest setting variables using ERB, and then checking those in the logic instead - for example:

```
condition = <%= condition.to_s %>

exampleFunction = ->
    if condition
        alert("condition met!")
    else
        alert("condition not met!")
```

This will mean that all of the code is available when debugging/running, and makes the ERB template a lot easier to manage with regards to indentation.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, but it solves my problem. And I agree that this is a cleaner way of doing things. Thanks!